# Can I use the UNID of a document to set a document to readonly?

Tags: xpages, xpages-ssjs

I have done many web searches and on specific search for "xpages UNID set to readonly ssjs" on stack overflow and think the answer is no - but I want to be sure.   Is there a ssjs command that can be used to set the mode of a document by using the UNID of document?  This would be like `context.setDocumentMode("document1","edit"); but would use the UNID instead of the currentDocument.

Comment: What are you trying to do? Read/Edit applies to data sources, not documents

Comment: It is difficult to describe and relates to another question I posted.  I thought I needed to get a handle on the currentDocument to make sure the document opens in read mode.  I solved the problem another way.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Read and Edit mode are UI constructs that have nothing to do with the underlying document. For a document you might have read, write or no access. So you can't set a document to read or edit mode.
What you do set to read or edit mode is the datasource (which might point to a document or something else) and a datasource doesn't have a UNID, it has a name (like document1).

Comment: Thanks for your reply. I hope I can trouble you for some further clarification,  I have a datasource defined in a panel.  I added a computed field to the panel that displayed the value of the currentDocument which looks exactly like a pointer (for example: com.ibm.xsp.model.domino.wrapped.DominoDocument@18971897).  Is there a way to find out which document or something else that it is pointing to?  Even though the underlying document does not change, the pointer number (@18971897) changes every time I refresh the panel say to switch from edit to read modes.  I find this odd.

Comment: Create a new question. Better chance of experts chipping in. The behaviour is not odd, but exactly how Java works everywhere. And always add the code sample of what you tried

Comment: OK, but first I will find a Java primer.

Comment: What you see is the result of .toString() which defaults to the object id. You want a property of that datasource